# Error retrieving a different model inside a route's setupController

Tags: ember.js

**EDIT:** I think I have found a solution. As I say in my question, the variable `profiles` is a promise so I've tried the following and it works:

```
...
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);

    var profiles = App.Profile.findAllByMaster(model.get('id'));
    profiles.then(function(data) {
        controller.set('profiles', data);
    });
}
...
```

**END EDIT**

I'm having the error: `Assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed [object Object]` when I try to get data from another model in the `setupController` hook.

The route is `MastersMaster` which associated model is `Master` and I try to get the `Profiles` models that belong to the current `Master`.

I'm not using Ember Data or something similar. It's just pure jQuery with $.ajax calls.

It's difficult to explain so here is the code excerpt:

```
App.MastersMasterRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Master.find(params.master_id);
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);

        // if I comment these two lines it works but I don't get the profiles (obviously)
        var profiles = App.Profile.findAllByMaster(model.get('id'));
        controller.set('profiles', profiles);
    }
});

App.Profile = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: '',
    master_id: null
});

App.Profile.reopenClass({
    findAllByMaster: function(master_id) {
        var profiles = Ember.A();

        return $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax/get.profiles.php',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { master_id: master_id }
        }).then(function(response) {
          $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            profiles.pushObject(App.Profile.create(item));
          });

          return profiles;
        });
    }      
});
```

If I `console.log` the variable `profiles` before doing the `controller.set` I see that it's a promise and not the array of `Profile` objects expected. I suppose I have to resolve the promise before but I don't have any idea.

P.S.: sorry my english :(

Comment: Since you have found the solution, you can post and accept it as an answer. Other users running into the same issue may find the answer useful. :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I didn't know I can vote my own answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in the edit, the problem was that the `findAllByMaster` method returns a promise so it has to be resolved before assigning it to the controller's property.

I suppose there is a more elegant or efficient way of solving it so another solutions are welcome.